# How do I create a GiST index on a PostGIS geometry column using DBIx::Class?

Tags: perl, postgis, dbix-class

I have a Postgres + PostGIS database with geometry columns.

I would like to add indices to them, e.g.

```
create index plot_idx_location on plot using gist (location);
```

I know how to create indices in DBIx::Class using the sqlt_deploy_hook method, but I am unsure what the syntax for add_index is to generate the above statement.

Reading the SQL::Translator documentation (http://search.cpan.org/~frew/SQL-Translator-0.11016/lib/SQL/Translator/Schema/Index.pm) seems to be of no help. There's no examples on using the "options" parameter, and breifly looking at the source code, I suspect it's not even supported.

So is there a way to do this, or do I need to hardcode the SQL statement in the sqlt_deploy_hook method instead?

Answer (score -1):

DBIx::Class itself doesn't generate DDL queries, SQL::Translator does.
You have to generate such special indexes yourself, for example in an after 'deploy' method modifier in your schema class or with the deployment_statements methods.

Comment: Yes, did you read my answer? No sqlt_deploy_hook is not the correct place because [DBIx::Class::Schema::sqlt_deploy_hook](https://metacpan.org/module/DBIx::Class::Schema#sqlt_deploy_hook) says: 'Note that sqlt_deploy_hook is called by "deployment_statements", which in turn is called before "deploy". Therefore the hook can be used only to manipulate the SQL::Translator::Schema object before it is turned into SQL fed to the database. If you want to execute post-deploy statements which can not be generated by SQL::Translator, the currently suggested method is to overload "deploy" and use dbh_do.'